# implementing a registration class

Tags: java

hi i am a totally new guy on JAVA OO concepts ,and this is my first time programming,i am currently stuck on how to create a registration class and a class which will store all the registration info, this is what i have done, 4 classes, a Account class, a Staff class extend Account,a Student class extend Account, and a dataStorage class to store the informations and to extract them when needed.

```
public class Account {

 private String name;
 private String department;
 private String username;
 private String password;

 public Account()
 {
 } 
    public Account(String nm,String dep,String user,String pass) 
    {
     name = nm;
       department = dep;
     username = user;
     password = pass;
    }

    public void setName(String nm)
    {
     name = nm;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
    ..... other accessors
}
```

/**/

```
public class Student extends Account {

 private String studentNRIC;
 private String studentID;

 public Student(String n, String nr, String id, String dep, String user, String pass)
 {
  super(n, dep, user, pass);
  studentNRIC = nr;
  studentID = id;
 }

    public void setStudentNRIC(String nr)
    {
     studentNRIC = nr;
    }

    public String getStudentNRIC()
    {
     return studentNRIC;
    }
    ....accessors

}
```

/**/

```
public class Staff extends Account {

 private String staffID;

 public Staff(String n, String id, String dep, String user, String pass)
 {
  super(n, dep, user, pass);
  staffID = id; 
 }

    public void setStaffID(String id)
    {
     staffID = id;
    }

    public String getStaffID()
    {
     return staffID;
    }


}
```

/****/
    import java.util.*;

```
public class DataStorage 
{
    ArrayList<Account> staff = new ArrayList<Account>();      
    ArrayList<Account> student = new ArrayList<Account>();  

    public DataStorage(Staff aAcc) 
    {
     staff.add(aAcc);
    }

    public DataStorage(Student aAcc)
    {
     student.add(aAcc);
    }

    public String msg()
    {
     Staff sf = staff.get(0);


    return staff;
    }
}
```

Comment: a) and now you'd like to be graded? or what's the question? b) your DataStorage class could be renamed to AccountDAO, where DAO is a common abreviation for Data Access Object, a common pattern

Comment: ... DataStorage is a bit strange though. no `add(Account a)` or `getAccount(String nm)`? What is `msg()` supposed to do?

Comment: a) i am stucked on how to continue, the datastorage class is not yet finished i am wondering if i can check whether the account passed is of type Staff or Student, so i can add the Staff accounts into staff arraylist and student accounts into student array list,i am also stucked on how to create a method that can retrieve information on either the staff or students from the arraylist.
b)i read a book on head first java and have not come across the DAO yet, so i dont know about it, but i will go learn about what is it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good so far.  One thing that you could do is to move the ID (`staffID` and `studentID`) up to the `Account` class, calling it something like `accountID`.  It seems that all accounts that you create need an ID, so moving this up makes sense.

One benefit of this would be to simplify your `DataStorage` class by having a single `Collection`.  Even if you would like to keep your `Staff` and `Students` separate, you could also use `Map` instead of a `List` in `DataStorage`, as this would make lookups faster and easier.

Comment: hi i have not yet learned about what is Collection or a Map , that is why i have used arrayList.

Comment: an ArrayList is a sort of collection, and it implements the `List` interface.  `Map` also falls within the collections framework, and a benefit with `Map` is that you can store objects with a lookup key.  In your case here, the key could be the `accountID`.

Comment: thanks,i just read about it and it seems that the key must be Unique, does this mean when i am putting in values there will be put(staffMembers,"John") and the next thing that will be put will be put(staff2Members2,"Tim")? because the key must be unique

Comment: I would use the ID as the key:  `put(account.getID(), account)`.  That way you could easily access a `Student` or a `Staff` object by passing in the ID of the account in question.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataStorage class needs some corrections:

```
public class DataStorage 
{
    ArrayList<Account> staffMembers = new ArrayList<Account>();      
    ArrayList<Account> students = new ArrayList<Account>();  

    // Default constructor
    public DataStorage() {
    }

    public void addStaffMember(Staff aAcc) 
    {
     staffMembers.add(aAcc);
    }

    public void addStudentMember(Student aAcc)
    {
     students.add(aAcc);
    }

    public Student getStudentById(String id)
    {
    }

    // More retrieval methods
}
```

You will usually want to hava more retrieval methods (get by department, name, id). Some will return a single item and some a list. If you are only interested in retrieving accounts by id, you could use a Map instead of a list. The truth is that to support all retrieval methods, you would need a relational database of some kind. If you are looking for a naive solution, keep the ArrayList and iterate through all members to find the ones you are looking for.

Comment: i do not understand returning a student object, i am pretty new on the topic polymorphism , my idea is to login the person based on his created account and he will be directed to a GUI that will display his information.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the answers i have come up with a new DataStorage class with HashMap object, note that i have not full grasp how HashMap works and this is what i have partially done, and would like to ask am i going in the right direction? A creation of a test class works, i am able to get the a value.

```
import java.util.*;

public class DataStorage 
{
    HashMap<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();  
    HashMap<String, Staff> staffMembers = new HashMap<String, Staff>();  
    //Default constructor
    public DataStorage(){
    }

    public void addStaffMember(Staff aAcc) 
    {
     staffMembers.put(aAcc.getAccID(),aAcc);
    }

    public void addStudentMember(Student aAcc)
    {
     students.put(aAcc.getAccID(),aAcc);
    }

   public Staff getStaffMember(Staff aAcc)
   {
   return   staffMembers.get(aAcc.getAccID());
   }

}
```

/*** test***/

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataStorage ds = new DataStorage();
        String name = "John";
        String ID = "0900477A";
        String Department = "ENG";
        String username = "ky";
        String pass = "ky";

        Staff sf2 = new Staff("Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim");
       Staff sf = new Staff(name, ID, Department, username, pass);
       ds.addStaffMember(sf2);
       ds.addStaffMember(sf);
      Staff temp = ds.getStaffMember(sf2);

       System.out.println(temp.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: TIP: Do not use capitals as field names / variable names. The are by convention reserved for class / interface / enum definition (here 'ID' and 'Department' violate that rule).
TIP: Start using Unit-tests for testing classes http://testng.org/ http://junit.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

Here some test class, as it would have been written with JUnit.

```
// Tests related to the Staff class
public class StaffTest {

    // This test should be successful, as all argument are correct
    @Test
    public void testCreateStaffMember() {
        String name = "John";
        String staffId = "0900477A";
        String department = "ENG";
        String username = "john";
        String password = "secret";
        new Staff(name, staffId, department, username, password);
    }

    // This test should throw an IllegalArgumentException, as the name is required.
    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testCreateStaffMemberNameNull() {
        String name = null;
        String staffId = "0900477A";
        String department = "ENG";
        String username = "john";
        String password = "secret";
        new Staff(name, staffId, department, username, password);
    }

    // This test should throw an IllegalArgumentException, as the name is required.
    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testCreateStaffMemberNameEmpty() {
        String name = "";
        String staffId = "0900477A";
        String department = "ENG";
        String username = "john";
        String password = "secret";
        new Staff(name, staffId, department, username, password);
    }

    // More constructor test follow


    // This test should be successful, as all getters, should return the given input values.
    @Test
    public void testValidateGetterMethods() {
        String name = "";
        String staffId = "0900477A";
        String department = "ENG";
        String username = "john";
        String password = "secret";
        Staff staff = new Staff(name, staffId, department, username, password);
        Asset.assertEquals(name, staff.getName());
        Asset.assertEquals(staffId, staff.getStaffId());
        Asset.assertEquals(department, staff.getDepartment());
        Asset.assertEquals(username, staff.getUsername());
        Asset.assertEquals(password, staff.getPassword());
    }

    // More tests...
}
```

```
// Tests related to the DataStorage class
public class DataStorageTest {

    @Test
    public void testAddStaffMembers() {
        DataStorage ds = new DataStorage();
        ds.addStaff(createJohn());
        ds.addStaff(createAlan());
    }

    // Here you deside, as the designer off the application, what should happen!
    // Will the second John, override the first John? As they have the same ID? 
    // Or will an exception be thrown, because the staff member with that id 
    // already exists?
    @Test
    public void testAddStaffMembersSameName() {
        DataStorage ds = new DataStorage();
        ds.addStaff(createJohn());
        ds.addStaff(createJohn());
    }

    Staff createJohn() {
        String name = "John";
        String staffId = "0900477A";
        String department = "ENG";
        String username = "john";
        String password = "secret";
        return new Staff(name, staffId, department, username, password);
    }

    Staff createAlan() {
        ...
    }
}
```